# add visual studio chart to powerpoint 

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, charts, powerpoint

I have been searching for a while and yet not able to identify how I would be able to export a chart created in visual studio 2010 using c# into a excel file. 
this is the code which creates my chart

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("zz");
            chart1.ChartAreas["zz"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chart1.ChartAreas["zz"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas["zz"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;

            chart1.Series.Add("q");
            chart1.Series.Add("w");

            chart1.Series["q"].Color = Color.Aqua;
            chart1.Series["w"].Color = Color.BurlyWood;

            chart1.Series["q"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
            chart1.Series["w"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

            for (int j = 0; j < textAdded.Count; j++)
            {
                chart1.Series["q"].Points.AddXY(j + 1, Convert.ToDouble(textAdded[j]));
                chart1.Series["w"].Points.AddXY(j + 1, Convert.ToDouble(textAdded2[j]));
            }  string ppt_fName = @"U:\ChartAdd.pptx";
            PowerPoint.Application myPPT = new PowerPoint.Application();
            myPPT.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            myPPT.Presentations.Open(ppt_fName);


            PowerPoint.Slide s = myPPT.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;
            PowerPoint.Chart ctrng = null;
            //fails due to cast problem
            ctrng = (PowerPoint.Chart)chart1;
```

it does not let me add the chart onto a powerpoint slide and was wondering how this could be achieved

Comment: how do you create your chart??

Comment: i ahve jus put up then code that creates my chart

Comment: Is it possible to add a chart from c# directly to powerpoint? My impression was, that that is impossibly (sadly).
You could try interop (SLOW!) or epplus (faster, but only xlsx files)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the chart as image then add the image to your powerpoint.